# Other platform to socialize information like FLUIDDB?

Tags: database, nosql, social-networking

In its official website, http://fluidinfo.com/, it is described as the following:
"FluidDB is a platform for the web of things, each represented by an openly writable "social" object".

In http://eu.techcrunch.com/2009/08/31/fluidinfo-a-database-aiming-to-socialize-information/, it is described as "Fluidinfo – a database aiming to socialize information".

I like the idea to socialize information, but it seems FluidDB is not suitable to enterprise applications.

Have you found other similar platforms? Please share your opinion here.

Thanks,

Ying

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think FluidDB is not suitable for enterprise?

Terry

Comment: For enterprise has a lot of structured information, which is legacy information resources. FluidDB is suitable for a totally new social platform.

Comment: probably be better to use a question comment then make an answer to ask a question.